# Referencing screen height and width in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How do I reference the screen height and width in vb.net? For example, the bottom right corner's locations, the top right corner's locations, etc.

I tried `My.Computer.Screen` but couldnt find anything that told me the size.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use:

```
My.Computer.Screen.Bounds
```

or:

```
Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
```

[Bounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.bounds.aspx) is a rectangle that provides the size.  Alternatively, you can look at the [WorkingArea](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.workingarea.aspx), which will not include the task bar and docked windows.

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like:

```
My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Size.Width
My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Size.Height
```

Answer (score 0):

For WPF you can use:

```
System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth

System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

dim height as integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height
dim width as integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width

Answer (score -1):

Insert this code into form_load. I put some resolutions...

```
    Dim dw As Double
    Dim dh as Double


    Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width
    If (Width = 1366) Then
        dw = 1
    ElseIf (Width = 1920) Then
        dw = 1.4055
    ElseIf (Width = 1280) Then
        dw = 0.9379
    End If

    For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
        c.Width = CInt(CDbl(c.Width * dw))
    Next

    Height = My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Size.Height
    If (Height = 768) Then
        dh = 1
    ElseIf (Height = 1080) Then
        dh = 1.4062
    ElseIf (Height = 1024) Then
        dh = 1.3333
    End If

    For Each g As Control In Me.Controls
        g.Height = CInt(CDbl(g.Height * dh))
    Next
```