# Vb.Net Application Screen Capture and Save it as a pdf

Tags: vb.net, screen, capture

I have this small application which capture the screen and save it as a pdf. I am running this application on my PC which has 1080P primary display and 1080P TV as an extended display. When i put the application on the extended TV display (full screen mode) it doesn't capture entire screen. It capture only 1/4 of the screen. But i want to capture the entire screen. How do i fix this. Please help

Here is the code;

```
 Private Sub SaveForm_shift1()

    Dim yesterday As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    Dim filePath As String = "C:\Autodesk" + yesterday + ".jpg"

    Dim bmpScreenshot As Bitmap = New Bitmap(Width, Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    Dim gfxScreenshot As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot)
    gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Me.Location.X, Me.Location.Y, 0, 0, Me.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
    Try
        gfxScreenshot.Dispose()
        ' Save the screenshot   
        bmpScreenshot.Save(filePath)
        saveToPdf_shift1(filePath)
        deleteImg(filePath)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Referencing screen height and width in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344342/referencing-screen-height-and-width-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to get a Bitmap with all the screens

```
Public Function GetScreenShot() As Bitmap
    Dim bmp As Bitmap = New Bitmap(Screen.AllScreens.Sum(Function(s As Screen) s.Bounds.Width),
                                   Screen.AllScreens.Max(Function(s As Screen) s.Bounds.Height))
    Dim gfx As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
    gfx.CopyFromScreen(New Point(0, 0), New Point(0, 0), bmp.Size)

    Return bmp
End Function
```

If you have strange staggered screen positions, the empty areas will be black in the resulting bitmap.